# Time Picker Control

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, ajax, timepicker

I don't know if what I need is applicable or not , But I know that there is a lot of Date picker controls (asp.net , Ajax , Javascript , ... etc) , But Can I find a Time picker control looks like a Watch and enable me to select time from it or that is impossible

Thanks in Advance

Comment: First of all you should select type of your application. It makes sense to look for a Time Picker Control for a specific platform and a specific language. There are a lot of different (free and not free) controls for your aim.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery plugin that does what you are trying to do -

http://code.google.com/p/cantipi/

So yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

try  https://github.com/jonthornton/jquery-timepicker -  this project has not been abandoned